# Unable to collect values on int array in java/android

Tags: java, android

i am trying to collect some values in int array,which are from the web service by consuming it.Here i am using SOAP method for the consumption.

when i am trying to collect the values in int array, i am unable to run the emulator.

How to overcome this error? Please find my source for reference.

**Main_WB.java**

```
 public class Main_WB extends Activity 
 {
EditText edt1,edt2;
TextView txt_1;
Button btn;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    edt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        getTMSChart(edt1.getText().toString(),edt2.getText().toString());
    }     
    });
  }

 private void getTMSChart(String FromDate,String ToDate)
 {
     txt_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

     System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");        
     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);        

     envelope.dotNet = true;

     String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
     String URL = "http://54.251.60.177/TMSOrdersService/TMSDetails.asmx";
     String METHOD = "GetTMSChart";

     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);        
     request.addProperty("FromDate", FromDate);               
     request.addProperty("ToDate", ToDate);

     envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
     HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

     try 
     {
         androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + METHOD, envelope);

         SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

         SoapObject root =  (SoapObject) ((SoapObject)(result).getProperty(0)).getProperty("NewDataSet");

         int tablesCount = root.getPropertyCount();


      for (int i = 0; i < tablesCount; i++)
      {
         SoapObject table = (SoapObject) root.getProperty(i);
         int propertyCount = table.getPropertyCount();

      for (int j = 0; j < propertyCount; j++)
      {           

    //  String orderNo =  table.getPropertyAsString("Order_No");
    //  String freight =  table.getPropertyAsString("Freight_Rate");
    //  String percent =  table.getPropertyAsString("Margin_Percent");


       int orderNo = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Order_No"));
       int freightRate = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Freight_Rate"));
       int marginPercent = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Margin_Percent"));

       int[] ord = new int[orderNo];
       int[] frei = new int[freightRate];
       int[] margin = new int[marginPercent];


     // whatever you do with these values

       txt_1.setText(ord);
       txt_1.setText(frei);
       txt_1.setText(margin);
          }                   
       }
    }   
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
    }   
    }    }
```

Comment: @VVS i am getting this (The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (int[])) message,when i hover the curzor on the line txt_1.setText(ord);

Comment: what do you want to do? you can only set String to a TextView. You are trying to set an int array

Comment: @nandeesh i am trying to collect the values in int[] array,the values are from the webservice by consuming it.and i am trying to print those values in a single textview,how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   int orderNo = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Order_No"));
   int freightRate = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Freight_Rate"));
   int marginPercent = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Margin_Percent"));

   int[] ord = new int[orderNo];
   int[] frei = new int[freightRate];
   int[] margin = new int[marginPercent];


 // whatever you do with these values

   txt_1.setText(ord);
   txt_1.setText(frei);
   txt_1.setText(margin);
```

What are you trying to do here? From looking at that piece of (useless) code it seem like you lack basic programming knowledge and should perhaps read some more tutorials.

That said I'm pointing out what you're actually doing there:

```
    int orderNo = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Order_No"));
```

Here you request the property "Order_No" as a string value and convert it into an int. So far so good.

```
    int[] ord = new int[orderNo];
```

Here you create an int-array with an amount of elements equal to `orderNo`. So if your orderNo is 12345 you create an int-array with 12345 elements. I don't think that is what you intended.

```
   txt_1.setText(ord);
```

Here you pass that huge (unintialized) int-array as a parameter to the setText method of txt_1. That method obviously wants a string value and not an int-array.

So what are you trying to do?

**EDIT:**

To answer your question regarding creating the int-array:

```
int[] ord = new int[propertyCount];
int[] frei = new int[propertyCount];
int[] margin = new int[propertyCount];

for (int j = 0; j < propertyCount; j++)
{           
    int orderNo = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Order_No"));
    int freightRate = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Freight_Rate"));
    int marginPercent = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Margin_Percent"));

    ord[j] = orderNo;
    frei[j] = freightRate;
    margin[j] = marginPercent;

}                   

// process the arrays;
```

I assume that you want one array per table so I create the arrays **outside** the inner loop and fill them within the loop.

Afterwards you can process these arrays. Beware that the arrays are recreated for every table in the outer loop.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually i'm trying to collect the values in int array and then send it to next screen through intents

Comment: I don't see where you're using intents?

Comment: i didn't use intents yet,yet to use,but before that i need to know how to collect those values in int array...can you please tell me how to collect those values in int[] array?

Comment: I have an another doubt will i ask you?..please

Comment: @Android_user: Ask your question in a way that everybody (including me) can answer and benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a compilation error, and the error is quite self-explanatory:

```
The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (int[])
```

This means that the argument of the method `setText()` must be of type CharSequence, but that you are calling it with an argument of type `int[]`, which is not a CharSequence.

Transform the `int[]` arrays to Strings, and, as String implements CharSequence, pass the resulting String to `setText()`. For example:

```
txt_1.setText(Arrays.toString(ord));
```

Moreover, I don't really see the point of calling setText() with three different arguments on the same text field.